# Python removing specific elements from nested list

Tags: python, list

I have a nested list of tokenized words, and I'm trying to remove specific words that are in another stopwords list. However, if a word appears in the stopwords list, the entire list is deleted rather than just the specific word. How do I get around this?

```
# Original list
a = ['huey', 'duey', 'luey']
b = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'gold']
first_list = [a, b]

first_list
```

This produces the output:

`[['huey', 'duey', 'luey'], ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'gold']]`

```
stop_words = ['huey', 'duey']

second_list = [subl for subl in mylist if subl[1] not in stop_words]

second_list
```

This produces the output:

```
[['red', 'blue', 'green', 'gold']]
```

What I am after is something that produces an output:

```
[['luey'], ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'gold']]
```

Comment: [list(set(d)-set(stop_words)) for d in first_list]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
second_list = [[y for y in x if y not in stop_words] for x in first_list]
```